# Problem with clickable Images in lua (Psych engine)

Tags: lua

Once i created the image "door" i tried to add some dependencies for once clicked to load the song "Basement" and when ingame once clicking the image it does nothing, i dont even get errors.

```
function onCreatePost()
    setPropertyFromClass('flixel.FlxG', 'mouse.visible', true)
    makeLuaSprite('door', 'door', 10, 20);
    setScrollFactor('door', 0.9, 0.9);
    scaleObject('door', 1.8, 1.6);
    addLuaSprite('door', false);
end

function onUpdate()
    if mouseClicked('left') then
        if objectsOverlap({mouse}, {door}) == true then
            loadSong('BASEMENT')
end
end
end
```

Song needed to load once clicking image "door"

Comment: Is this `objectsOverlap({mouse}, {door})` correct?  What are the values of variables `mouse` and `door`?

Comment: mouse has to be corect because thats the variable given by the game but i dont know how to give an image a variable since i belive the image gets a variable automatically from the line ```makeLuaSprite('door', 'door', 10, 20);``` but im not sure

Comment: [This reference](https://gamebanana.com/tuts/15333) lists `objectsOverlap` as accepting two string arguments (`objectsOverlap(obj1:String, obj2:String)`). With no meta-programming, `{door}` is an array-like *table*, with `door` as its first element. Is the mouse even considered an *"object"* in this engine? What about using these [mouse position functions](https://github.com/ShadowMario/FNF-PsychEngine/wiki/Lua-Script-API:-General-Functions#mouse-position-functions) to check if the click is within the bounds of your sprite? I cannot find a complete API reference for this engine.

Comment: If i were to use the mouse X and Y i need to give the door image a variable that would connect to all door image attributes and i dont know how to do that, can you please provide an example? I would greatly appreciate it.